# Blank page showing while rotate screen in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css

Placed popup mask in page. its showing white space while rotating mobile screen for a second.

please find the sample,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
             -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                backface-visibility: hidden;
            }
            .skMask {
                height: 1500px;
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 0.9;
                background-color: #000000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="skMask"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have tried using backface-visibility option. but still its showing on rotate.

Comment: Packed your code into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLs4yv4z/), tested [direct link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/aLs4yv4z/show/) with Mobile Safari on iOS 8.1.2, nothing white to see.

Comment: Siguza, Please try full screen mode and in android phones. Verified in Samsung devices the white space is showing for a second. I don't know it's a device behavior or I have to add any CSS hacks.